# Software that auto checks output vs the expected output (Pics inside)

Tags: testing, ide, compare, output

As the title says, I need a tool (IDE maybe?) that with given test cases and inputs, checks the expected outputs vs the one my program gives back.

We have a web (app?) like this at university, but I haven't been able to find something that does this anywhere else, although it seems like the code is copied from somewhere else as it is in English (not the native language here). A picture of the website/app is linked below.

[Website I talked about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYF6C.jpg)

I need this for an online programming course I am making, so a website that does this would be ideal, but a windows application would probably do the job just fine. Linux isn't an option.

Anything helps, but if it can be similar/exact, one page, side to side, no hassle of switching tabs etc, that would be great, because the course is aimed at total beginners.

Oh, also, it isn't on this picture, but for example if the expected output was "12345" and mine was "12346" it highlights the 5 and 6.

Thanks to everyone in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found software that can to this online. They are called code autograders and quite a few actually exist.

For my needs and purposes autograder.com and stepik.com get the job done.